# Button not responding to onClick method

Tags: java, android, button

I am developing an Android app and I want to inflate a dialog with the press of a button (I've already done that), but one specific button does not work, and I don't really know why.

My code:

```
public class SearchUser extends AppCompatActivity{

private static final String TAG = "SearchUser";

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchUser);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchUser.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.searchpopup, null);
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    });
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

LAYOUT XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/user"
    mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mapView"
    mapbox:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mapView"
    mapbox:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearchUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/search_user"
    mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mapView"
    mapbox:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mapView"
    mapbox:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/log_out"
    mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mapView"
    mapbox:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mapView"
    mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="-34.6131500"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-58.3772300"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12"
    mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10">

</com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:text="@string/crear_fiesta"
    android:textColor="@color/mapboxGrayLight"
    mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I have tried putting a toast message inside the onClick method but nothing happens, so I guess it just does not enter there.

Anyone know why? Thanks for any answer :D

Comment: your layout xml file?

Comment: That code, as posted, will not compile. Please provide a [mcve]. Furthermore, it's unclear exactly what the issue is. Please be specific.

Comment: you have used `btnSearch` but not initialized it anywhere before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the wrong `onCreate()`, replace it with:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

**Edit**: are you sure that this xml should be inflated in class `SearchUser`? 
 Do you have a class `MainActivity` like the xml states?

Comment: Yes I do have a class Main Activity, but does that mean that I cant use a button from the activity_main in another class?

Comment: So `activity_main.xml` is used for 2 activities?

Comment: Yes, it should be. But I guess the problem is there. I have just investigated and in the xml file there is a line that says tools:context=".MainActivity". I think this has to do with the stuff that will work on that xml, and that is why its not working. Any idea?

Comment: `tools:context=".MainActivity"` is not compiled and you could use the same xml for multiple activities, but maybe the problem is here. If you can't find any other solution just create another layout and copy paste the existing to it. If this solves the problem then you know. If not then it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `btnSearchUser` button below the `MapView` in XML.

You've also configured `MapView` with `match_parent`, which is not applicable to a constraint layout parent. Set the height and width of `MapView` to 0dp as well.

Comment: That shouldnt make sense, I also have two buttons on top of the mapview and they do work.